# Powershell format cell in csv

Tags: powershell

info.csv

```
name, address, id
Superman, Metropolis, 123456
```

I need id cell to be a 1000 separator with no decimals

```
name, address, id
Superman, Metropolis, 123,456
```

Any advice on how to do this in powershell? I have 11 different columns to format and do not want to open the file everyday in Excel to format cell.

Thank you in advance

Comment: CSV is a plaintext format that doesn't store formatting information. If you insert a comma that comma becomes part of the data (which must be put in double quotes then to prevent the comma from being interpreted as a delimiter).

Comment: Thank you, Very good point. I do have quotes around all data in the fields. "Superman","Metropolis","123456"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the data when you import and select as shown in below example:

```
Import-Csv .\input.csv | Select Name,address,@{N="id"; E={[String]::Format("{0:N0}",[int]$_.id)}}
```

This will give the output as given below:

```
name     address    id     
----     -------    --     
Superman Metropolis 123,456
```

Comment: That worked and I am very grateful. Thank you.  Any id cell that previously was blank now has a 0. Is there a way to not populate the 0 in blank fields?

Comment: You can try this: `Import-Csv .\input.csv | Select Name,address,@{N="id"; E={$ID=[String]::Format("{0:N0}",[int]$_.id); If($ID -eq 0){""}Else{$ID}}}`